# JSP Expression works in JSTL tags but not in Struts 2 tags

Tags: jsp, struts2, jstl, scriptlet, struts-tags

I am using JSTL and Struts 2 in my project. I am trying to set a value in the scope using JSTL and Struts 2 tag as follows:

```jsp
<div id="id1"></div>
<div id="id2"></div>
<%               
   int b=10;
 %>
<c:set var="test2" value="<%= b %>"/>
<s:set var="test3" value=" <%=b%>" />
<script>
 document.getElementById("id1").innerHTML="${test2}"; //10
 document.getElementById("id2").innerHTML="${test3}"; //nothing is displayed.
</script>
```

The output is `10` only. My doubt is why the expression `<%= b %>` works in `<c:set>` tag and does not work in `<s:set>` tag?

Answer (score 0):

Struts tags doesn't allow scriptlects in the tag's attributes. But you can try

```
<s:set var="test3"><%=b%></s:set>
```

Comment: the JSTL tag <c:set..> allows scriptlets in the tags attributes but why <s:set..> does not allows,is there any design issue?

Comment: May be a design, it's only accept OGNL expressions.